# add shortcode to p element and reload it

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to add a shortcode to the page after the page loaded and here are my requirements

1- add a shortcode to p element when I select an option from a select element.

** here I was able to add the shortcode as a text but I don't get the expected value from it and this is because the page was loaded so I had to load the element that has that shortcode.

2- load shortcode's element but it has to have the new added shortcode

** because when you just reload the element all what you did on point 1 will got deleted if you will just reload the element.

here is the code

```
<form action=""><label for="">خزنات الروايات المتوفرة</label><select id="select_novel" onchange="gAj()">
<option value="Youjo Senki">ملحمة تانيا الاثمة</option>
<option value="Isaac">اسحاق</option>
</select></form>

<p id="g_a" style="text-align: center;"></p>

<script>
function gAj() {
    var x = document.getElementById("select_novel").value;

    document.getElementById("g_a").innerHTML = `[mycred_my_balance user_id="${x}" title="لدى خزنة الرواية الأن"]`;
    }
```

code that i tried

i tried to add PHP code here but doesn't work will "Unexpected token '<'"

```
// var php_c = <?php echo do_shortcode(`[mycred_my_balance user_id="${x}" title="لدى خزنة الرواية الأن"]`); ?>
```

I tried to reload the element by this way but it didn't work .. look on point to 2

```
// $("#g_a").load(location.href+" #g_a>*","");
```

Comment: This shortcode only shows data, it doesn't manipulate anything on the server side, right? Then it would probably make more sense, if you did this without any extra requests. Render _two_ hidden `p` elements with the respective shortcode output inside already - and then dynamically _show_ the one that corresponds to the selected option via JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe i worked with your opinion, it is good but not the best.. because i have not only two options but about 50 and it will increase by time.

Comment: @CBroe but thank you very much for your help... i was about to gave up

Answer (score 0):

1- the HTML list

```
<select id="select_novel" onchange="gAj()">
  <option value="kol 1">option 1</option>
  <option value="kol 2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

2- add shortcodes for all options in HTML and make them hidden and have 2 classes

class 1 will be given two all divs that contain hidden shortcodes.

class 2 will be equal selected option value but (spaces " ") will be replaced with "_".

```
<div style="display: none;" class="gol kol_1">[mycred user_id="kol 1"]</div>
<div style="display: none;" class="gol kol_2">[mycred user_id="kol 2"]</div>
```

3- the javascript code

```
<script>
0- the function work only when you chose an option or rechose again
function gAj() {
  var pToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('gol');
  for(var i = 0; i < pToHide.length; i++){
      pToHide[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById("select_novel").value;
  var x_r = String(x).replaceAll(" ","_");
  document.querySelector(`.${x_r}`).style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

I didn't want to explain the javascript anymore so one last thing
thank you @CBroe he gave me the hint that lead me to this solution and thanks to everyone who helps noobs like me.